# Trying to make a table row that deletes itself

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the top row of a table delete itself, every 5 seconds, using javascript.    My javascript looks like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);   
}, 5000);
```

which gets it to delete the top row after 5 seconds.  Is there a way to reset the `setTimeout` to begin counting down again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it looks like you are looking for the functionality of `setInterval`:

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);   
}, 5000);
```

If you would still like to use `setTimeout` you would want to call another `setTimeout` inside your `function(){ ... });` that does the same thing. Basically have a function that keeps calling itself with a `setTimeout` like so:

```
(function loop() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0); 
    setTimeout(loop, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: thank you sir.  have a upvote, although you won't see it until I've been on here longer.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside of a function and call it again.

```
function deleteRows(){
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);  
       clearTimeout(t);
       deleteRows();
    }, 5000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setInterval()` instead. Inside your callback function check for number of rows and if the row exists then delete it, if it doesn't remove time interval.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/n2yg4fv2/ (I used 1 second delay to make it faster)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` .

Check the difference between them here: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

***setTimeout(function, milliseconds):***

> Executes a function, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds.

***setInterval(function, milliseconds)***

> Same as setTimeout(), but repeats the execution of the function continuously.

Therefor, you can rewrite your code as following:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);   
}, 5000);
```

Then if you want to stop the execution of that timer function, you can use:
`window.clearInterval(timer);`